# c++ calls opencv related function and is packaged into dll, c# can not call it

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

c++ is called dll after calling opencv related function, c# can not call it.but if I don't use the opencv in my dll,it works well.just like the imread function in the opencv package.

When I packaged the dll, I used opencv.dll and its lib file. In C++, their related environment has been configured. I don't know if c# needs to configure the related opencv environment, or what other methods are needed.

```
[c++ code]-Packaged into test.dll
#include<memory.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include"test.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"opencv_world310.lib")

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int test();
int test()
{
    Mat readImage = imread("D:\\pic\\pic1.JPG");
    int rowPic = readImage.rows;
    return rowPic;
}

[c# code]-Call the test.dll
namespace testOilDetectionCsharp
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        [DllImport("test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        extern static int test();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                int num = test();
                textBox.Text = num.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

just like the test function,I have the pic path,but in c#, calling the function will theoretically return the number of lines in the image. This is not the case. The imread function in opencv doesn't work.
**THANKS!**

Comment: Does the application crash?? What is the exception you get?

Comment: Thanks,this application doesn't crash,but it always returns 0,the imread function in opencv doesn't work,so I can't get the number of rows and columns of this test picture.

Comment: Well then there are 2 posibilities. Imread has a problem or c++/c# interfacing has a problem. To verify please run a c++ console app with above code and check the results. Imread is a very reliable function and I ve used it many times. May be your image path is wrong or image is corroupted.

Comment: Unsafe block is not needed here because we are not using any pointers. 
If you are using visual studio please put a break point on "return rowPic;" line and check the readImage. If its null, it is because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format. Check this out also https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

Comment: THANKS,When I use C + + to packagethe DLL, I use C + + to call the DLL, and the result is what I want, but the return value of C# call is always 0. At first, I passed the path string into the DLL as a pointer, so I used unsafe. Later, I passed the path directly instead of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it I think it's a dll not found exception. I've encountered many of these. Probably you can figure it out by running EventViewer (its a utility inside windows). Event viewer will have an entry on what is the missing DLL. Probably copying all the opencv dlls to the execution path will fix the issue.

Comment: OK,I will try it now.Thanks.

Comment: After I try, it still doesn't work. The return result of the function is still 0.I found that it's not lack of other DLLs, it's just that the imread function in opencv can't be used.